# Windows 10 -- Host based security trashing disk, unusually high read/write of (CIM) WIM Repository, OBJECTS.DATA

Tags: windows, hard-drive, security, resource-usage

we have a box where the endpoint antivirus is slowing down the system considerably with disk read/writes.

The file that it appears to be interested in is "OBJECTS.DATA" from the local WIM repository. We are not in a situation where we are permitted to exclude this directory. Have attempted regenerating the WIM repository using the CLI tool, which upon inspection is not corrupt, but upon forcing it to rebuild there is no change.

Any ideas on what might be going on are much appreciated!

Comment: I am guessing that the file gets written too often, and therefore changes often. I would add to an ignore list.

Comment: If you use Process Monitor to see these file operations, does the stack help? Ideally configure symbols.  It should at least tell you the module generating the read/write operations but you may need to contact the endpoint security vendor to gather their thoughts.  The PML file seems like something they would want, the benefit they have is that they have the private symbols of the modules so know the "why".